# Is there a USB brick / portable battery that will work with the MacBook (2015+, USB-C) and regular USB?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, usb, battery

?I have the early 2015 MacBook with USB-C charger. I want to have *one* brick for that AND my iPhone. I also bought a USB-A to USB-C cable, but I can't find a USB-A brick with enough power to charge my laptop. Is there a brick (or preferably portable battery) that will allow this

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to have one charging brick, then buy Apple’s USB-C to lightning cable. The you can use your MacBook’s charging adapter to charge either the MacBook or the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you chance to check this folks: https://www.powertraveller.com ?

For instance, this product may be helpful: https://www.powertraveller.com/en/shop/portable-chargers/professional/powergorilla/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This [Zendure 5-port USB-C Hub Portable Charger](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B075Q5YTFJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) (45 watts) should pretty much meet every requirement you can think of, including concurrently charging other devices while charging a MacBook.  Charges both legacy USB devices as well as the newer USB-C ones such as MacBook Pros- Oh, and you can even use it as a hub apparently (*I haven't tried this yet however*)

Please note the USB cable used with the USB brick/batter makes a **HUGE** difference in charging performance.  I spent ages researching cables and the [Anker USB-C to USB-C Thunderbolt 3.0 Fast Charging and Data Transfer Cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B076D76DRQ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) (19.7 in) gives me a full 19.8 volts- the same voltage when using the 87 watt Apple Power Adapter- vs about 5v for the cheap USB cables.  Cable is barely 1.5 feet long, so can't be placed too far from your MacBook.

***Why not use an Apple USB-C/Thunderbolt cable?*** Because it received 1-star reviews in the Apple Store, so I started looking on Amazon and found this Anker USB-C cable which had 4.5 starts for 31 reviews on Amazon.co.uk.

In below pictures is included one of the Xendure X6 charging my 2018 MacBook with the Anker USB-C cable:

[image: Zendure X6 Ports]
[image: Zendure X6 Profile View]
[image: Zendure X6 charging with Anker USB-C cable]